# My edit suggestion got rejected based on wrong markdown diff

Tags: support, stack-overflow, edits, suggested-edits

I edited an answer and suggested a small change that was greatly improving the post. This suggestion got rejected. When I looked into the revision history I noticed a strange behavior.

The edit I suggested was made under someone else's username - apparently the one who reviewed and improved my suggestion. So far everything seems fine: ([Revision link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13286266/revisions))

[image]

But then I looked into my suggested edit itself to see what happened to it and saw this:

[image]

Of course the difference here is too minor to be approved. **But what is displayed here was not my suggestion!** (That suggestion can be seen in the revision 2 in the image above)

So what happened here? Was this due some strange timing issued in improving and approving my suggestion without marking it as helpful?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your edit suggestion was made *after* someone else had made most of the same edit. [Revision number 2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13286266/revisions) clocked in at 10:00:24, and your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/958337) was recorded at 10:00:35.

The system only recorded the difference between the second edit and yours, and that difference amounted to a minor edit.

A case of bad luck, I'm afraid!

Comment: The guns in the west are really fast! :)

Comment: /me blows the smoke away from his gun barrel. *Pffffft*

Comment: Interesting - as I saw this line in the edit box when starting to edit: `try (byte[]) getValue(key).getBytes();` so in this rare case there seem to have two people seemed to have clicked on "edit" at the same time... Thanks for clarifying nonetheless.

Comment: @Spontifixus: There is no notification to show someone else is editing the post already, and it is impossible to tell who started to edit first. All I know is that you *started* your edit before the other editor had submitted his changes.

Comment: The link to the edit page normally gets disabled if another user is editing that post. There are several circumstances however where this mechanism does not come into effect: One of the users has had loaded the page already or both clicked at the same time... Conclusion: As you said: A timing issue and a case of bad luck ;)

Comment: @MartijnPieters actually there is a message after somebody else finish to edit the same post, something like "this post has been edited, your edit will be submitted only if [can't remember more]"